# How to make a list of pairs from 2 vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

Say I have

```
X = seq(1,10,1)
X0 = c(-Inf,X)
X1 = c(X,Inf)
```

How can I make a list of pairs `(-Inf,1);(1,2);...;(10,+Inf)`

This gets close but not quite

```
R) test = mapply(c,c(-Inf,thresh),c(thresh,Inf))
R) test
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,] -Inf    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40    45    50    55    60    65    70    75    80    85    90    95
[2,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50    55    60    65    70    75    80    85    90    95   Inf
```

Comment: `mapply( c , X0 , X1 , SIMPLIFY = FALSE )`. This is an exact dupe.

Comment: Or just `Map(c , X0 , X1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
mapply(c, X0, X1, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] -Inf    1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2
# ...
# [[11]]
# [1]  10 Inf
```